# Is there a way to measure time taken for SQL query to execute without fetching the results in Java?

Tags: java, sql, database, performance-testing

So I am writing a DB performance test tool which have to measure time it takes for some queries to execute, however it works with Big Data and these queries generate millions of rows each and therefore generating huge network traffic between my machine and the DB Host. My question is how to run the queries from java application where I know when did the query finished its execution but without fetching the resultset?

does the following Piece of code exclude all the rows travelling through the network?

```
        //start recording time
     Bool someName = statement.execute(sqlStatement);
        //stop recording time
```

Comment: You could do SELECT COUNT(*) only instead of returning rows perhaps in your queries if it is ok to modify them?

Comment: I would suggest to create a stored procedure with your SQL query and not returning the rows, so you will just need to execute the SP in your java code.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the already existing queries

Comment: Bad wording on my part, I of course meant to make a copy and modify the copy unless you need to measure them exactly as they are.

Comment: In Postgres you can do an `explain (analyze)` - which DBMS product are you using? But in the end you should test this including the network traffic, because you typically don't run statements in production where you do not retrieve the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly run a `CREATE TABLE (SELECT query)` command and measure the time. Drop the table afterward.

MySQL [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html)